# Logarithmic equation question

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have the following equation and I'm supposed to choose whether or not it's true.

$\log_7(5x^2) = 2 \log_7(5x)$

According to my textbook, the solution is False because it should look like this instead:

$\log_7(5x^2) = 2 \log_7(\sqrt5x)$

I don't really get how the square root got in there. Shouldn't the first equation be true since the square is only on the $x$ and, therefore, it would become:

$\log_7 5 + 2 \log_7 x $

Comment: Your book is wrong! It should be $2\log_7(\sqrt{5}|x|)$ !

Comment: " Shouldn't the first equation be true since the square is only on the x and, therefore"  ... No.  That is precisely *why* the first equation is *false*.  For the first equation to be true, the square would have to be on the $(5x)^2$ not $5(x^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\log_7 (5x^2) \ne 2 \log_7 (5x)$ because $x$ is being squared, not $(5x)$.

In actuality:  $\log_7(5x^2) = \log_7 5 + \log_7 x^2 = \log_7 5 + 2\log_7 x$

[Assuming $x > 0$.  Otherwise we should assume $\log_7 x^2 = \log_7 (-x)^2 = 2\log_7 |x|$].

Whereas had the question been *instead* $\log_7 (5x)^2$ then $\log_7 (5x)^2 = 2\log_7 5x$.

In answering the question, the text is assuming you, the student, *will* make an error and say "Well, gosh.... Isn't $\log_7(5x^2) = \log_7 (5x)^2 = 2 \log_7 5x$?" (Presumably right before you eat dirt and shove a crayon up your nose).

In which case the book is shaking its head sadly and the sorry excuse it presumes its students must be, and explains that, no $5x^2=5*(x)^2 \ne (5x)^2 $ but $5x^2 = ([\sqrt 5] x)^2$ so $\log_7(5x^2)$ would actually by $\log_7(5x^2) = \log_7([\sqrt 5]x)^2 = 2\log_7([\sqrt 5] x)$  (And as Adam points out in a comment you book would *still* be wrong if we don't know $x > 0$).

So that you didn't see where the $\sqrt 5$ came from just means you aren't as dumb as the book assumes you to be.

Note:  $\log_7 5 + 2\log_7 |x| = 2\log_7 \sqrt 5|x|$ (and $\log_7 5 = \log_7 \sqrt 5^2 = 2\log_7 \sqrt 5$) but the RHS is certain *less* natural and more convoluted than the LHS.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the explanation I was looking for. Just wish I didn't feel like sticking a crayon up my nose now...

Comment: It kind of bothers me when a book assumes a student will make an error.  Otherwise deciding $\log 5x^2 = 2\log \sqrt{5}|x|$ is, although correct, preposterously convoluted.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\log_a N^b = b\log_a N$ you have
$$2\log_7 (\sqrt{5}x) = \log_7 (\sqrt{5}x)^2 = \log_7 (5x^2).$$
Another property of logarithms is that $\log ab = \log a + \log b$. So
$$\log_7 (5x^2) = \log_7 5 + \log_7 x^2 = \log_7 5 + 2\log_7 \lvert x\rvert.$$

Comment: But would this apply if the exponent is directly on the x, not outside the parentheses?

Comment: I edited the answer. Those steps show that you cannot take the 2 out if it is only exponent of $x$.

Comment: Based on your example, wouldn't it mean that the original equation should result in log7 of 25x^2?

Comment: @blizz No. Why?

Answer (score 0):

$$\log_7(5x^2) = \log_7(\sqrt 5|x|)^2 = 2\log_7(\sqrt 5|x|)$$